# can non-unique index avoids the duplication of records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table in which I am not able to create primary key as well as unique indexing,the reason is, table contains employee's salary data,employee code is unique but because pay codes are different and each pay code associated to individual employee,that's why we are allowing the duplication of records.

Now the problem is,salary data is pushed by the third party vendor into the shared database and  when we migrate the salary data into our database, then it happened that data records inserted twice or thrice times.

for example, suppose third party pushed 5000 records, now we need to fetch those 5000 records into our database, but it happened last month that data fetched 3 to 4 times, it becomes 20,000 records instead of 5000, the reaso was simple we don't have any validation in our table.

Now i was suggested to create unique index to avoid duplication, but because employee code is repeated, i am not able to do it.

Now we are left with non-unique index and I am not able to understand , is it really helpful in order to avoid duplication.

My main purpose is to avoid duplication.
Please suggest me the better solution.

Here is some data

```
   SALARY_REPORT_ID EMP_NAME    EMP_CODE    PAY_CODE    PAY_CODE_NAME   AMOUNT  PAY_MODE    PAY_CODE_DESC   YYYYMM  REMARK  EMP_ID  PRAN_NUMBER PF_NUMBER   PRAN_NO ATTOFF_EMPCODE  REFERENCE_ID
    13488158    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    104     7427    1   HOUSE RENT ALLOW    201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488159    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    100     23885   3   BASIC PAY   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488160    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    103     9590    1   DEARNESS ALLOW. 201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488161    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    100     191800  1   BASIC PAY   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488162    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    303     40000   2   PF SUB-PAY(GPF) 201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488163    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    502     20  2   G.T.I.S.    201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488164    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    503     72  2   SCLIS   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488165    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    999     69441   1   NET EARNING 201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488166    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    998     195692  2   GROSS DEDUCTION 201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488167    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    997     265133  1   GROSS EARNING   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488168    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    134     16006   3   WAGE REVISION ARREARS   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488169    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    108     400 1   CONVEYANCE ALLOWANCE    201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488170    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    134     16025   3   WAGE REVISION ARREARS   201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488171    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    506     600 2   GSLI(Board Employee)    201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
    13488172    Mr. Javed Jafri 91559037    312     155000  2   INCOME TAX  201802      119     22782303        150025  1-268
```

More Indent way
[image]

Comment: I can't see your data, so I can't answer, but I would say that in general every important table in your schema should have a primary key.  If you can't create one with just a single column, then use multiple columns.  This will avoid a headache later on.

Comment: If your index is only on the employee code then that won't help; is there some other column you can include in the index, such as a unique index on a combination of employee code and published-date? Of course, you'll still need to handle the duplication - either by handling/ignoring the exceptions, or modifying the load to exclude duplicates in the first place (e.g. `where not exists`, which also implies you can identify the unique condition somehow).

Comment: To apply a index, you need data that's valid with the index. So before you can create a unique index, you need to make the data itself unique with the same criteria. Oracle cannot do this itself

Comment: ohkk see my edits i posted the table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then you should create a multi-column unique index on (employee_id, pay_code). You must find a combination of columns that should be unique and create an index based on that.

Comment: Or maybe it's better to create more tables

Comment: @simo - obviously the presented table is denormalised but normalisation wouldn't solve the actual problem, which is the compound candidate key.

Comment: @APC If you cannot find a one column primary key for your table, you should normalize it. I will never forget my IT teacher, she was saying that all the time!

Comment: @simo - I don't want to diss your teacher, I'm sure she was a marvel, but that is wrong. Business keys are frequently compounds of multiple columns. Now we might choose to add a single column synthetic or surrogate key to act as the primary key, because that's more convenient for certain tasks. (and that's what the OP has here in SALARY_REPORT_ID). However, a synthetic primary key has no business meaning (it's usually generated) so unless we also enforce a unique constraint on the candidate key we get duplicate business records.

Comment: @APC diss her all day long if you want :D. But yeah, I understand your point of vision, clearly It's better to creare a composite pk

Comment: can anyone of you came up with normalised solution of the same i demonstrated above

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the unique constraint you want is a compound constraint on `your_table(EMP_CODE,PAY_CODE)`;

Only you cannot create that constraint while you have duplicate values for that combination of columns. So you need to clean up the data. Fortunately Oracle can support you in this exercise.

Firstly you need to create an Exceptions report table (if you don't already have one). Oracle defines a standard structure for this table, so you (or your friendly DBA) should run this script: `@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlexcpt.sql`.

Then create the constraint:

```
alter table your_table 
    add constraint your_table_uk unique (EMP_CODE,PAY_CODE)
    exceptions into EXCEPTIONS;  -- or whatever you called your reporting table
```

This will fail but it will populate the EXCEPTIONS table with ROWIDs for all the violating rows. Now you can go through your table and delete all the duplicate rows.

If you think that might be a long exercise, or - it seems to be the case - you don't wish to clean up the duplicates, you should use the NOVALIDATE option. That will at least prevent the situation getting worse. For this to work you need to create a **non-unique** index on (EMP_CODE,PAY_CODE) before adding the constraint. When you add the unique constraint Oracle will use the existing index to enforce it, without any problems. But we cannot use the NOVALIDATE option with a unique index. [Find out more](https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/novalidate-constraints-no-really/).

But make sure you do get around to cleaning up the duplicates!

Comment: its a salary data of government employees, and it is in lakh we are not able to delete it.

Comment: Then you must use the NOVALIDATE approach and live with the consequences.