# How I check existing record and avoid redundant data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, both are situated at different server and belongs to different schema.

**Table 1** : `SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_[monthYearSuffix]`-Same Replica of Table 2.

**Table 2**: `XXMPCD_SALARY_DETAIL_TABLE`-Contains employee's salary related data,each employee having multiple pay code like `HOUSE RENT ALLOW,DEARNESS ALLOW, NPS-Company Contri(Earning), BASIC PAY, NET EARNING, GROSS DEDUCTION, GROSS EARNING, GROSS DEDUCTION, NET EARNING, BASIC PAY, GRADE PAY`.

***So Employee code repeated multiple times and hence we are not able to maintain primary key or unique index.***

Suppose 1000 records pushed in **TABLE 2** which I need to copy exactly in my **TABLE 1**. This is handle by my SPRING service class a GUI is available in which we simply click on migrate button and services running in background fetch the data from **TABLE 2** and insert the same in the **TABLE 1**.

There is two column inside **TABLE 2**

```
1.PICK_DATE
2.IS_DATA_PICKED
```

If both of these data contain `null` that simply means that data is not migrated into our **TABLE 1**, we updated the same columns after successful migration by acknowledging, so the next time the data will not be available for migration.

### PROBLEM

Now suppose we migrated the 1000 records from **TABLE 2** to **TABLE 1**.
What I done, I go back to my SQL DEVELOPER, choose 3 random records and set their `PICK_DATE` & `IS_DATA_PICKED` to `NULL`.

Now I migrated the same another time and those 3 records inserted again.
That means replication of 3 records, 1000 records becomes 1003.

### Now what I want to check:

If same data existed, than record should be updated not inserted, means overwrite.

```
TABLE 1:SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_092018
SALARY_REPORT_ID
EMP_NAME
EMP_CODE
PAY_CODE
PAY_CODE_NAME
AMOUNT
PAY_MODE
PAY_CODE_DESC
YYYYMM
REMARK
EMP_ID
PRAN_NUMBER
PF_NUMBER
PRAN_NO
ATTOFF_EMPCODE
REFERENCE_ID
```

**

```
TABLE 2:XXMPCD_SALARY_DETAIL_TABLE         
EMP_NAME
EMP_CODE
PAY_CODE
AMOUNT
PAY_MODE
PAY_CODE_NAME
YYYYMM
REMARK
PUSH_DATE
PICK_DATE
IS_DATA_PICKED
ERROR_MESG
REFERENCE_ID
PRAYAS_ERP_ORG_ID
ERP_ORG_ID
PF_NUM
PRAN_NO
VERIFIED_BY
```

Comment: *"So Employee code repeated multiple times and hence we are not able to maintain primary key or unique index"*  As I replied to [one of your earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52312770/146325`), you need a **compound unique constraint** on `(emp_code, pay_code)`.

Comment: How it will be beneficial for us and how do I create the same, please demonstrate.

Comment: Actually I already told yuo, for the current scenario, its not possible to clean up the data, i just want to run update if data is existed in the table, if not then insert.

Comment: So what columns uniquely identifies a row?

Comment: Just to be clear: do you mean both tables don't have unique constraints and so both contain duplicate rows?

Comment: Yes both tables doesn't have unique constraint, because of this, the duplication of same record can be possible, which i want to avoid.